# Is there a word for a "love of storytelling" or storyline

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't mean "loving to read stories" but instead a word that describes a love of the content/storyline for any media. For example if there is not a good storyline in a game I start playing. I'm a movie critique because the way the scenes play out, what they decide to show and what they don't are crucial and just as important as the music they choose.

My love of storylines/content/storytelling is the case for any creative piece I create. Do you know if there is a word out there for this?

Comment: There's a difference between liking a work with a strong storyline (gripping plot, full of surprises without being unbelievable, strong sense of narrative progression, etc), and being interested in how a story is [represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_structure) in a work of literature (the order it is told in, what is omitted, etc). A narratologist is someone who studies how stories are told.

Answer (score -2):

The Greek suffix [-philia](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/philia) is used to describe a love of or affinity towards something; sometimes used in a sexual/erotic sense.

Although I have been unable to find such a word to describe a love of storytelling, one may be created using Greek meanings. The only Greek prefix that is similar in meaning to a story/narrative/tale is:

> #### [mythos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mythos)
>
> - Anything delivered by word of mouth: a word, speech, conversation, or similar; a story, tale, or legend, especially a poetic tale.

Unfortunately, the common English conception/usage of the prefix **myth** is to describe untrue or [mythical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mythical).

The word Mythophilic/Mythophila, on paper, would seem to be a logical combination of suffix and prefix, but no such definition currently exists to support that. Actually, an [unofficial definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mythophilia) does exist that hints more towards the sexual/erotic usage of the suffix -phila.

Unfortunately, that hypothetical usage is probably the only thing close to the word you are looking for.